# How do I convert form data from multiselect dropdown list from array to string In angular 7 Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, multi-select

I have a form in which there is a field which dynamically loads data from the database into a ng-multiselect dropdown list. I want to store that form data in database using post request, which is not working. When there are all text input fields it is working fine. My research tells me I have to convert the ng-multiselect  values to string for it to work .

Component.ts

```js
export class AssociateDetailsComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{
  
  
  //Variable for dropdown multiselect
  str : string;
  //list : Skills[];
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems =[];
  dropdownSettings = {};
  readonly rootURL= 'http://localhost:67764/api';
  
  emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
  constructor(private associateService: AssociateServiceService,
    private data : DataService, private http : HttpClient) { }
  
    

 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.rootURL+ '/Skills').toPromise()
    .then(res => this.dropdownList = res as Skills[]);

    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'SkillsId',
      textField: 'Skill',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 100,
      allowSearchFilter: false
    };
    this.selectedItems = [
      { SkillsId: 3, Skill: 'java' }
    ];

    

    //Shared service for data transfer between forms
    this.AsId=this.data.AsId;
    
    this.associateService.formData={
      Name: '',
      AssociateId: this.AsId,
      Skills:'',
      Hobbies : '',
      Experience : '',

    }
```

component.html

```js
postAssociateDetail(formData: Associate){
    //JSON.stringify(formData);
    
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/AssociateDetails',formData);

  }
```

```html
<div class="col s6">
 <div class="row">
   <h3><div class="col s6">Name</div></h3>
   <h3>{{AsId}}</h3>
    </div>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="card">
   <div class="sm-jumbotron center center-align">
     <h2>Please Provide Below Details</h2> 
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col s12">
         <form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="OnSubmit(form)">
            <div class="formgroup"> 
                <label data-error="Required field!">AssociateId</label>                 
                <input type="text" placeholder="AssociateId" class="validate" name="AssociateId" #AssociateId="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="associateService.formData.AssociateId" required>
            </div>     
            <div class="formgroup">
                <blockquote>
                    List your skills
                   </blockquote>
                   <ng-multiselect-dropdown
                     name ="Skills"    
                     type="input-field"    
                    [placeholder]="'Skills'"
                    [data]="dropdownList"
                    #Skills="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="associateService.formData.Skills"
                    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                    >
                  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>                              
                                             
               
            </div>  
            

            <div class="formgroup"> 
                <blockquote>
                   Please enter your interests and hobbies 
                  </blockquote>
                                 
                <input type="text" placeholder="Hobbies" class="validate" name="hobbies" #Hobbies="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="associateService.formData.Hobbies" required>
            </div>
              <div class="formgroup"> 
                  <blockquote>
                     Please share your experiences.
                    </blockquote>
                                     
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Experience" class="validate" name="experience" #Experience="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="associateService.formData.Experience" required>
              </div>
              
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s6">
                <div class="formgroup">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large waves-effect">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col s6">
                  <div class="formgroup">
                      <button  type="reset" class="btn btn-large waves-effect" (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  </div>       
         </form>
       </div>
       
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Backend

'[HttpPost] public async Task<IActionResult> PostAssociateDetails([FromBody] AssociateDetails associateDetails) { if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(ModelState); } _context.NewAssociateDetails.Add(associateDetails); await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); return CreatedAtAction("GetAssociateDetails", new { id = associateDetails.Id }, associateDetails); }'
```

'

Comment: You are using multiselect, that is working fine, right? Also you are able to fetch the data based on your multiselect options, right? What next are you trying to do? Store the what data in the database? Sorry it's not clear to me.

Comment: there are two tables one is skills table using which i am populating the ng-multiselect. and then there is a table which is associatedetails table(having skills column) which is taking the details when I am submitting the html form above using post request .When I post it using the same service it is not posting the details in the database . in the backend i have used c# .There must be some way to post the multiselect details along with the form. the skills that i have populated from Skills table I want to post the selected skills into a column in associatedetails table.

Comment: Did you inspect if your request is hitting the server and is in the format you are expecting? Can I see the request you are making to you backend?

Comment: when I am just posting simple input fields post is working but after adding multiselect I am not able to do the same      '[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAssociateDetails([FromBody] AssociateDetails associateDetails)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            _context.NewAssociateDetails.Add(associateDetails);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction("GetAssociateDetails", new { id = associateDetails.Id }, associateDetails);
 }'

Comment: No I was not asking for the backend code. Just the HTTP POST request being sent to the backend.

Comment: Yeah I have added the post request too